Is there a way to configure policies/preferences for chrome
I want to set some Chrome policies on my Android device. (Samsung Galaxy A71)
I know this is possible on PCs.
I ran into similar question about chrome-flags, but couldn't figure out a way to do it for policies yet.
In addition I've found this Q&A about Linux, and it didn't get me far.

May be possible as described here but you may need an MDM managed device.
